# How to create a desktop shortcut to a program, including its icon in Cinnamon

Tags: shortcuts, icons, cinnamon

I read a few articles about how to create a desktop shortcut in Cinnamon, but none has answered my question completely. I know I can create a launcher and then set a path to run, but that leaves me with a iconless launcher.

Or I can make a link to the binary itself and then place this link in the desktop, but that achieves the same as the former approach.

When I start a program from the "Start" menu, it has an icon next to it. I want to have a shortcut to the program having *the* icon. How do I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, you can do that through right-click popup menu. Consider this closed, as I cannot answer myself yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a desktop shortcut by right-clicking on a program in the start menu and selecting *Add to desktop*.